# how to Initialize reference vector object to vectors of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I have created

```
 vector<vector<int>>*  vec2vec = new vector<vector<int>>; .
```

I have

```
 vector<int>* v
```

that has elements {0,1,2}

how do I initialize `&v` to `vec2vec` ?

Comment: `&v` is a `vector<int>**`, `vec2vec` doesn't have that type, so you can't. Could you explain exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `*v` not `&v` since container element type `vector<int>` is different from type of `&v` i.e. `vector<int>**`

```
vec2vec->push_back( *v )
```

Comment: note that this stores a copy of the vector pointed to by `v`. OP is unclear but I think he wants `vec2vec` to actually refer to the thing pointed to by `v` (which isn't possible unless he changes the type of vec2vec)